# Is the $Ψ$ in the Schrödinger Equation the same as the $Ψ$ in Exact Equations First Order Differential Equations?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation

The Schrödinger equations have the term $\Psi$, which is the wave function.

http://scienceworld.wolfram.com/physics/SchroedingerEquation.html

I do not know what type of equation the wave function in the Schrödinger Equations is but I noticed that the symbol $\Psi$ is also used in Exact Equation First Order Differential Equations.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iEpqcdaJNTQ&index=4&list=PL96AE8D9C68FEB902

Does the symbol $\Psi$ mean the same thing in the Schrödinger Equations as it does in exact Equation First Order Differential Equations?  If it doesn't mean the same thing what type of equation is the wave function in the Schrödinger Equations?

Answer (score 5):

The Schrödinger equation is a partial differential equation. Its type depends on the Hamilton operator and the fact whether we have time-independent or time-dependent equation. In fact, it is not even strictly speaking a wave-equation in the [mathematical sense](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave_equation), because it is at most first order in the time derivative.

Arguably the most important Schrödinger equation is the [harmonic oscillator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_harmonic_oscillator), which is a second order partial differential equation. Most reasonable Hamiltonians will be at least second order, since they contain a term for the kinetic energy, which is of second order.

Hence, no, it is hardly ever (never?) an exact equation first order differential equation.

Also note that the number of symbols is limited so you are bound to find the same symbols in similar but different locations. But that's okay, they are only symbols and their meaning should be clear from the context.

Comment: Of course the Schrödinger equation is a wave equation.

Comment: The symbol $\PSI$ can be used for anything you please, just like $X$.

Comment: @my2cts the term “wave equation” is usually reserved for $\partial_t^2 u = c^2\nabla^2 u$. It is generally not possible to write the Schrödinger equation in this form.

Comment: @leftaroundabout There are two Schroedinger equations: the time dependent and time independent one. In particular, the time dependent Schroedinger equation is a wave equation

Comment: @JasonBorn time-dependent Schrödinger is _an equation that has wave solutions_ – but so does a simple advection equation. Neither are wave equations. Mathematically, the Schrödinger equation is rather a complex-valued diffusion equation.

Comment: @leftaroundabout The time dependent Schroedinger equation is an inhomogeneous wave equation with the inhomogeneity corresponding to the scattering potential.

Comment: @JasonBorn if you're going to argue about this, then make an _argument_ (give a reference, or show a mathematical reformulation). Just restating your claim brings us nowhere.

Comment: @leftaroundabout One may mathematically formulate the time dependent Schroedinger equation as:

$$\left(\Delta+\frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2}\right)u(t,x)=V(x)u(t,x),$$
where $V(x)\in C^\infty_c(\mathbb{R}^n)$ denotes the scattering potential. Note that outside the support of $V$, the above equation is nothing other than the wave equation. I refer to the book of Roger Newton on the inverse Schroedinger scattering problem.

Comment: @JasonBorn that's almost the Schrödinger equation, but with $\frac\partial{\partial t}\to\frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2}$. How did you to this transformation?

Comment: @Ruslan https://aip.scitation.org/doi/pdf/10.1063/1.527503 see equation (2.2)

Comment: @JasonBorn that equation has minus before the second time derivative, unlike the one in your comment. But anyway, that paper doesn't assert that this is the time dependent Schrödinger equation: it names it _plasma wave equation_. Moreover, its solutions will differ from those of Schrödinger's one at least by phase velocities of waves of different frequencies.

Comment: @JasonBorn _iirks_. Yagle (or rather, [Rose et al](https://aip.scitation.org/doi/pdf/10.1063/1.526015) from whose work this stems) are being really sloppy with terminology. You can start with a time-independent Schrödinger equation, ok. But the solutions to this are only plane waves if the scattering potential has a very small compact support. Then you can calculate the Fourier transform, but simply equating $\omega = \|\mathbf{k}\|$ is... haphazard. That's not a dispersion relation that makes any sense for the Schrödinger equation.

Comment: ...at least the $t$ parameter you introduce this way has little to do with physical time.